# How to pass array to a server and receive it on another device

Tags: android

I'm developing a game in Android and i want to add multiplayer feature but very simple one just to test the concept.

What i need is : How to pass a 2D array from one device to another and vice versa using PHP Post and Get methods ?, So after each action the passing method is invoked to send the array to the server and the other device get it via Get method in PHP.

Move info : The code will be very simple i just want to open connection to send the array (int) via post to the server and receive it on another device via get. The game will be just for testing in 2 devices no more.

The server will have 2 php files, one for posting and one for getting.

**If you find it hard to understand me, Then please if you know how to to pass array from android to web server, Tell me how and that would be awesome for me.**

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Comment: use JSON to format your array?

Answer (score 0):

To send data from the device to the server you can use the HTTP utility classes provided by Android SDK and explained in this [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html).

Pushing data from the server to another device is more difficult (traditional HTTP requests are for client=>server requests). Google provides a dedicated service for that: [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html).